# How to apply featuretools to output of featuretools?

Tags: python, pandas, feature-engineering, featuretools

I want to create complex features like [(a-b)/c or (a-b)/a]
This can be achieved by running feature tools multiple times so that first one creates features like a-b or a+b or a/b and then next run would create more complex features.
As I try to do this using the following code samples:

```
import featuretools as ft

def multi_level_feature_creation(X, trans_primitives_per_level): 
    feature_matrix = X

    
    for i,trans_primitives in enumerate(trans_primitives_per_level):
        print("Level: ", i)
        print("Columns: ", feature_matrix.columns)
    
        es = ft.EntitySet(id = 'dataset')
    
        dataframe_name = "data" + str(i)
    
        es = es.add_dataframe(
            dataframe_name=dataframe_name,
            dataframe=feature_matrix,
            index="index" + str(i)
        )        

        feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(entityset = es, target_dataframe_name = dataframe_name,
                                      trans_primitives = trans_primitives)
        
        
    return feature_matrix, feature_defs





X = df.drop(["target"], axis=1)
y = df["target"]


features_per_level = [ 
    ['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric', 'subtract_numeric', 'divide_numeric', 'multiply_numeric_scalar'],
    ['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric', 'subtract_numeric', 'divide_numeric', 'multiply_numeric_scalar'],
#         ['add_numeric', 'multiply_numeric', 'subtract_numeric', 'divide_numeric', 'multiply_numeric_scalar']


]



feature_matrix, feature_defs = multi_level_feature_creation(X, features_per_level)

print(type(feature_matrix))
feature_matrix.head()
```

When I run it with single level it works fine.
The issue occurs when running on more than one levels:

```
ValueError: Cannot add a Woodwork DataFrame to EntitySet without a name
```

How to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your question.

It sounds like the desired goal is to create complex features. The desired features can be generated in a single run of `dfs`. Stacking `TransformPrimitives` on top of each other is not permitted in Featuretools. However, seed features can be used to generate the desired features. Click [here](https://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3E%200%20and%20feature_matrix.ww.name%20is%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature_matrix.ww.name%20=%20%22Df%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3E%200%20and%20feature_matrix.ww.index%20is%20None:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20feature_matrix.ww.set_index(feature_matrix.index)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20print(f%22ww%20schema:%20%7Bfeature_matrix.ww.schema%7D%22)) for documentation.

Here is an example call to `dfs`:

```
es = ft.EntitySet(id="test") 
es = es.add_dataframe(dataframe = df, dataframe_name="df", index="idx", make_index=True)

a_minus_b = ft.TransformFeature([es['df'].ww['a'], es['df'].ww['b']], primitive=ft.primitives.SubtractNumeric)
a_minus_b_over_c = ft.TransformFeature([a_minus_b, es['df'].ww['c']], primitive=ft.primitives.DivideNumeric)
a_minus_b_over_a = ft.TransformFeature([a_minus_b, es['df'].ww['a']], primitive=ft.primitives.DivideNumeric) 

fm, fd = ft.dfs(entityset=es, target_dataframe_name="df", trans_primitives=trans_primitives, seed_features=[a_minus_b_over_c, a_minus_b_over_a])
```

Please let me know if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question as yours.

Two methods:
1.Try to apply the answer here: [deep feature synthesis depth for transformation primitives | featuretools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65448806/deep-feature-synthesis-depth-for-transformation-primitives-featuretools)
basically:

create another ft.EntitySet() then use the feature_matrix from the previous step as input dataframe

2. Just use pandas to manipulate fm, probably easier.